# Custom Class variable overriden by some unknown process

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have a custom class which consists of a static ArrayList object. For some reason that I cannot seem to figure out, the elements in the object is getting overwritten when I call on the clear() method on **another** ArrayList object. This is what I'm talking about:

> Notice on the itemsArray.clear() line, I will explain further down below

```
public class AddItemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

// Global variables
// For the Description
private EditText descEditText;

// For the Price
private EditText priceEditText;

// Temporary array to store the list of items which will be passed into the Diner
public static ArrayList<Item> itemsArray = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // THIS HAS PROBLEM!!!!
    itemsArray.clear();
    // Set the content to use the activity_add_items xml file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_items);

    final ItemsListAdapter adapter = new ItemsListAdapter(this, itemsArray);
    // Find the ListView to display the adapter on
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.items_list);

    // Set the ListView with the adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button addDetailsFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_item_button);
    addDetailsFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Setting up a new dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AddItemsActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_add_dialog);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.add_item_title);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            Button num1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_1);
            Button num2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_2);
            Button num3 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_3);
            Button num4 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_4);
            Button num5 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_5);
            Button num6 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_6);
            Button num7 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_7);
            Button num8 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_8);
            Button num9 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_9);
            Button num0 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_0);
            Button numPeriod = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_period);
            Button numDel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_del);
            Button numAdd = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.key_add_item);

            // Properties for description field
            descEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.details_desc_input);

            // Properties for price field
            priceEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.details_price_input);

            // Keypad OnClickListener to append or delete digits in the price input field
            View.OnClickListener keyOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                // Program logic when one of the buttons is pressed
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    priceEditText.requestFocus();
                    CharSequence originalText = priceEditText.getText();
                    Button button = (Button)v;
                    // Prevents app from crashing when trying to delete an empty field
                    if (button.getText() == getString(R.string.details_button_delete_text)
                            && originalText != null && originalText.length()>0) {
                        // Deletes one character/digit, deletes '$' if required
                        if (originalText.length() == 2 && originalText.charAt(0) == '$') {
                            priceEditText.setText("");
                        } else {
                            priceEditText.setText("");
                            priceEditText.append(originalText.subSequence(0, originalText.length() - 1));
                        }
                        // Delete key does nothing instead of displaying 'Del'
                    } else if (button.getText() == getString(R.string.details_button_delete_text)) {
                        priceEditText.append("");
                        // Prevents a second period from appearing in the field
                    } else if (button.getText().toString()
                            .equals(getString(R.string.details_button_period_text))
                            && originalText.toString().contains(".")) {
                        priceEditText.append("");
                        // Adds a $ sign
                    } else if (originalText == null || originalText.length() == 0) {
                        priceEditText.append("$");
                        priceEditText.append(button.getText());
                        // Else, input the digit pressed
                    } else {
                        priceEditText.append(button.getText());
                    }
                }
            };

            // Add key OnClickListener to  add items into Diner's editItemsArray
            View.OnClickListener addOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                // Program logic when one of the buttons is pressed
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    priceEditText.requestFocus();
                    CharSequence originalText = priceEditText.getText();
                    Button button = (Button)v;
                    // If the input field is empty, do nothing. Else, add the items
                    if (originalText == null && button.getText() == getString(R.string.details_button_add_text)) {
                        priceEditText.append("");
                    // Adds the items into the editItemsArray ArrayList
                    } else {
                        Item itemToAdd = new Item(descEditText.getText().toString(),
                                Double.parseDouble(priceEditText.getText().toString().replace("$",
                                        "")));
                        itemsArray.add(itemToAdd);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Log.e("add item", "works");
                    }
                    Log.e("line1", "works");
                }
            };

            num1.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            num2.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            num3.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            num4.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            num5.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            num6.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            num7.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            num8.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            num9.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            num0.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            numPeriod.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            numDel.setOnClickListener(keyOnClickListener);
            numAdd.setOnClickListener(addOnClickListener);

        /*
        Request focus for the price input field such that focus is on that field when
        the dialog opens
        */
            priceEditText.requestFocus();
        /*
        Hide the appearance of any keyboard when the user presses on the price input field
        so the user only uses the provided in app customised keypad
         */

            // Hide default keyboard when focus is on this field
            priceEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager
                            .LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                    Log.e("testonclickclose", "works");
                }
            });

            priceEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
                }
            });

            priceEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return false;
                }
            });


            dialog.show();

            // Setting the size of the dialog
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }
    });

    Button addNextDinerActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.item_done_button);
    addNextDinerActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Assign the list of items to specified Diner (selected previously or
            // currently adding)
            // Get name of current diner
            String nameOfCurrentDiner = Diner.getCurrentName();

            // Iteration process to find the index of current Diner
            int indexOfCurrentDiner = -1;
            for (Diner list : AddDinerActivity.dinerArray) {
                if (list.getmDinerName().equals(nameOfCurrentDiner)) {
                    // Stores in index in a variable
                    indexOfCurrentDiner = AddDinerActivity.dinerArray.indexOf(list);
                }
            }
            // Instantiate a Diner object to be added later
            ArrayList<Item> array = getItemsArray();
            Diner dinerToAdd = new Diner(nameOfCurrentDiner, getCurrentBill(getItemsArray()), array);
            // Sets a new Diner object to the index position found
            AddDinerActivity.dinerArray.remove(indexOfCurrentDiner);
            AddDinerActivity.dinerArray.add(indexOfCurrentDiner, dinerToAdd);
            // Clears the editItemsArray when leaving activity

            // Brings the user back to Diner list page
            Intent addDiner = new Intent(AddItemsActivity.this, AddDinerActivity.class);
            startActivity(addDiner);
        }
    });
// Method to calculate the current individual's bill
public double getCurrentBill(ArrayList<Item> list) {
    double currentBill = 0;
    for (Item item : list) {
        currentBill += item.getmItemPrice();
    }
    return currentBill;
}

// Method to get current item array
public ArrayList<Item> getItemsArray() {
    return itemsArray;
}
}
```

> My Diner class is defined as below which consists of an ArrayList object named mDinerItemsList

```
public class Diner {

public static String currentName;

// To store the currentName
private String mDinerName;

// To store individual's total bill
private double mDinerBill;

// To store the individual's list of items (its description and price)
private ArrayList<Item> mDinerItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

// Class constructor
public Diner(String mDinerName, double mDinerBill, ArrayList<Item> DinerItemsList) {
    this.mDinerName = mDinerName;
    this.mDinerBill = mDinerBill;
    mDinerItemsList = DinerItemsList;
}

// Class constructor with Name ONLY
public Diner(String mDinerName) {
    this.mDinerName = mDinerName;
}

// Class constructor with Bill ONLY
public Diner(double mDinerBill) {
    this.mDinerBill = mDinerBill;
}

// Class constructor with ItemsList ONLY
public Diner(ArrayList<Item> mDinerItemsList) {
    this.mDinerItemsList = mDinerItemsList;
}

// Method to set the current name to identify current diner
public static void setCurrentName(String name) {
    currentName = name;
}

// Method to return the current name to identify current diner
public static String getCurrentName() {
    return currentName;
}

// Method to return Diner's Name
public String getmDinerName() {
    return mDinerName;
}

// Method to return Diner's bill
public double getmDinerBill() {
    return mDinerBill;
}

public void setmDinerName(String mDinerName) {
    this.mDinerName = mDinerName;
}

// Method to put an item (description and price) into Diner's list of items
public void putmDinerItem(ArrayList<Item> array) {
    mDinerItemsList = array;
}

// Method to return Diner's list of items in the form of ArrayList
public ArrayList<Item> getmDinerItemsList() {
    return mDinerItemsList;
}
}
```

At the press of a button in the activity, a single object containing the strings of descEditText and priceEditText will be added into the itemsArray. This array is then passed to mDinerItemsList during the period where I instantiate a new Diner object. These happens just before the AddItemsActivity ends. Through the debugging process, I have found that as AddItemsActivity is invoked the second time, the itemsArray.clear() somehow erases the mDinerItemsList of the Diner object which I instantiated previously. This happens everytime the activity is invoked. Therefore, I am unable to store any ArrayLists in mDinerItemsList for each Diner objects that I want to create. Where did I go wrong?? I've been trying to figure this out for hours! Please help!!!

Comment: The Problem is that you are just passing aroung your list instead of creating copies of it. So there is really only one List object but many variables that point to that list.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating further? When I assign the mDinerItemsList using the elements of itemsArray, shouldn't that variable be "tied" to the Diner object. Therefore, any changes to itemsArray shouldn't affect my Diner class variables right?

Comment: No idea what you mean with "tied". You are not creating a new ArrayList with the new Keyword. So no new list is created and you just assign your already existing list  to the mDinerItemsList field in Diner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that you are just passing around your list instead of creating copies of it. So there is really only one List object but many variables that point to that list.

For example: In your Diner constructor you simply assign the mDinerItemsList to the DinerItemsList that got passed.

```
// Class constructor
public Diner(String mDinerName, double mDinerBill, ArrayList<Item> DinerItemsList) {
    this.mDinerName = mDinerName;
    this.mDinerBill = mDinerBill;
    mDinerItemsList = DinerItemsList;
}
```

So when you do

```
ArrayList<Item> array = getItemsArray();
Diner dinerToAdd = new Diner(nameOfCurrentDiner, getCurrentBill(getItemsArray()), array);
```

You are simply passing the static List that getItemArray() returns to Diner and the new Diner Object will point to that exact same List.

To work around that Problem you can use the ArrayList Copy Constructor which will create a shallow copy (A seperate List pointing to the same objects as the original List):

```
mDinerItemsList = new ArrayList<>(DinerItemsList);
```

**Edit:** To clarify some very simple example code:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list2 = list1;
```

In the above example you will only have 1 List but have 2 variables pointed at it. calling list2.clear(); will also clear list1 (Because there is just 1 List that both variables point to). Your code does the same thing. It just passes around an Object reference but doesn't create a new one.

Comment: Yes! Your suggestion did solved the issue, you're a godsend, thank you! One more question in regards to the idea you said that no new List were created. I understood your explanation, however I'm confused as to why this line of code:

private ArrayList<Item> mDinerItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

does not instatiate a new List object? Does that mean I can erase the portion after the equal sign?

Comment: @L.KT `private ArrayList<Item> mDinerItemsList = new ArrayList<>();` will create a new empty ArrayList when the object is created, but then shortly after that by doing `mDinerItemsList = DinerItemsList;` you change the list that your class variable mDinerItemsList points to to the list you passed in the constructor. Since no variable any longer points to the empty arraylist, it will get dealt with by the garbage collector soon after. You can theoretically reduce the field declaration to just `private ArrayList<Item> mDinerItemsList;`

Comment: Your explanation helped me learned something today. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Diner constructor:

```
list = new ArrayList<>(passedList);
```

This way you are not setting the variable in your Diner object to the static reference in your other class. Instead, you are simply creating a new list in the Diner object, and filling it will the contents of the static list.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Diner(String mDinerName, double mDinerBill, ArrayList<Item> DinerItemsList) {
    this.mDinerName = mDinerName;
    this.mDinerBill = mDinerBill;
    mDinerItemsList = new ArrayList<DinerItemsList>;
}
```